# javascript [Object] inside my object instead of real data

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have the following js code https://repl.it/N0xy/0

 I am trying to push some objects into an existing one using some functions:

```
mylist.push(createMyObject(item.name, item.school, item.teacher))
```

the result contains :

```
 { result: true, count: 1, items: [ [ [Object], [Object] ] ] }
```

instead of :

```
     { result: true, count: 1, items: [ { name: 'Jacky', school: 'high', teacher: 'good' },
  { name: 'Tom', school: 'college', teacher: 'bad' } ] }
```

how can i fix this? 
thanks

Comment: It would be better if you add a runnable code snippet in the question.

Comment: The code in the link in the question works perfect on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lpch6t3c/

Comment: Post all your code in the question. Stackoverflow has runnable snipplets

Comment: *how can i fix this?* There is nothing to fix since values are there in `mylist` as expected, just that `console.log` hasn't evaluated the same for you.

Comment: If you add a runnable code snippet to the question you'll get it yourself! The code is just fine, it's the site you are using which is showing you the incorrect output.

Comment: You can force JSON output like this: `console.log("print my obj: %j", obj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to do `JSON.stringify(obj)` in the last statement. Everything else seems fine.

You might want to change the second last line to:

`obj.items = create();` as well.

or maybe `obj.items = obj.items.concat(create());`

Comment: yeah i see, but if don't stringify it, do those `[Object]` hold the info that I can see when I stringify them? because i can't stringify them at that moment, cuz i am passing it to another module to handle it. so i wanted to be sure that those object carry the info that they should carry.

Comment: Yes yes. They do hold the value. Its just how javascript prints them which is causing you issues. :)

Answer (score 0):

You pushed an array to `obj.items` in stead of the separate items. `create()` returns an array.

Try this:

```
create().forEach(function(item) {
   obj.items.push(item);
});
```

OR

```
let createdItems = create();
for(item of createdItems) {
    obj.items.push(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `console.log` at the end, wrap the `obj` in a call to `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
console.log("print my obj: ",obj);
```